# Javascript Promise Ready

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, promise, angular-promise

I have a class (LoadClass) which inits when the page loads, and opens an SQLite database in my case and executes a couple of queries. Now I want other components to only execute code when LoadClass has previously finished loading the database, but this must happen anytime. For obvious reasons, I only want to open my databases once. It should work something like this:

```
class LoadClass {

    // This executes directly on page load
    constructor() {
        this.load_my_database().then(function() {
            // My database finished loading, now my buttons may work.
        })
    }
}

function user_presses_button() {
    LoadClass.ready().then(function() {
        // Only now something
    })
}
```

How would I go about doing this using Promises?

Comment: How is this related to angular?

Comment: @echonax In my case it's an angular 2 project

Comment: So all you are asking for is how to write a singleton? I always thought Angular services provided that functionality out of the box.

Comment: You really [shouldn't make an asynchronous call from within a constructor](http://stackoverflow.com/a/24686979/1048572).

Comment: How much time is needed to finish database loading?

Comment: store the database loading promise and re-use it as needed. Can call `then()` on same promise as often as you want

Comment: Please read [ask]. Key phrases: "Search, and research" and "Explain ... any difficulties that have prevented you from solving it yourself".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
class LoadClass {

    private _ready_promise; 

    constructor() {}

    // This executes directly on page load
    page_load() {
        this._ready_promise = this.load_my_database();
    }

    load_my_database() {
        return new Promise(function(resolve) {
            // Do something...
            // Now my database finished loading, everything else may work.
            return resolve();
        })
    }

    ready() {
        return this._ready_promise;
    }
}

function user_presses_button() {
    LoadClass.ready().then(function() {
        // Only now something
    })
}
```